# Ajax call to output div

Tags: php, html, ajax

I need to do an ajax call where I am passing variables to another page (fetch_data.php). The same page (fetch_data.php) will contain the div output.

My challenge is that in the div tag there are "if" conditions and loops, which I am having trouble to embed in the div tag.

Adding single quote between html tags and a dot between php code does not seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
 $output .= 

              '                     <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                    <li class="page-item <?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
                       <a class="page-link" href="list.php?pageno=<?php echo $pageno-1 ?> " tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                       for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++)
                       {
                       ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php if($pageno == $i){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
                       <a class="page-link" href="list.php?pageno=<?php echo $i ?>">
                       <?php echo $i ?>
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                       }
                       ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
                       <a class="page-link" href="list.php?pageno=<?php echo $pageno+1 ?>" tabindex="+1">Next</a>
                    </li>
                 </ul>' ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put statements inside a string. Use concatenation.

```
$output = '                     <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                    <li class="page-item ' . (($pageno <= 1) ? 'disabled' : '') . '>
                       <a class="page-link" href="list.php?pageno=' . ($pageno-1) . '" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                    </li>';
for ($i = 1 $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
    $output .= '<li class="page-item ' . (($pageno == $i) ? 'disabled' : '') . '>
                       <a class="page-link" href="list.php?pageno=' . $pageno . '">' . $i . '</a>
                    </li>';
}
$output .= '<li class="page-item ' . (($pageno >= $total_pages) ? 'disabled' : '') . '>
                       <a class="page-link" href="list.php?pageno=' . ($pageno+1) . '" tabindex="+1">Next</a>
                    </li>';
```